# Windows 10: Missing brightness toggle from action center

Tags: windows, windows-10, brightness, action-center

[image]

As you can see the brightness toggle is missing and the keyboard key for that doesn't work as well, I tried to reinstall the driver from device manager, didn't work. The laptop is hp 2000. It disappeared 2 days ago, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can find to offer you, is the brightness slider in Power Options.  You can find in one of two ways:

- Right-clicking the Start Menu button, and it will be the third option.
- Type Power Options into the Cortana Menu.

At the bottom, you will see a slider for screen brightness.

I tried to find a way to repair the missing tile for brightness, but all the guides I come across state a method you've tried.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the slider is not there, i can see it on my new hp laptop but not on the laptop in question. not even in conrol panel!

Comment: You said that the slider disappeared two days ago.  Was there any event you noticed two days ago?  An update was installed, a new program or driver, something changed the registry?

Comment: It's not my laptop. I'm trying to fix it, the guy said he didn't notice anything

Comment: the issue still exists but since there seem to be no solution, I'll tell him to format the pc and I'll accept your answer to close the topic

Comment: @Lynob Sorry we couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: What a terrible OS.